# What if result of SPARQL query is a resource?

Tags: rdf, sparql

If a query like

```
SELECT * {?s ?p ?o}
```

returns `?o` as an resource(uri) like http://example.com#george_michael, how can I go deeper and get for example the `rdfs:label` of this resource in the same query?

Comment: In a comment to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21165839/1281433), you said that you'd already tried it.  Did you define the `rdfs` namespace correctly?  Questions on StackOverflow are typically best when they include code that's not working as you'd expect it to, and you can show the expected results and the actual results.  If you already tried something like this and it didn't return the results you were expecting, please add the _complete_ query (including prefix declarations) to the question, along with the actual results that you get, or the error message if it's an error.

Answer (score 2):

SPARQL is a language for querying graphs.  A SPARQL query is a *pattern* that can match a graph.  The pattern `?s ?p ?o` simply matches any triple.  If you want to match an additional triple, you just add a corresponding triple pattern to the graph pattern:

```
SELECT * {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  ?o rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

Of course, you mentioned “what if” `?o` happens to be a resource, which suggests that you might be interested in values of `?o` that *don't* have an `rdfs:label` as well.  In this case, you'd want to use `optional`:

```
SELECT * {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  optional { ?o rdfs:label ?label . }
}
```